# mongoDB Object DBCursor has no method 'sort'

Tags: mongodb

so i created a collection called `food` with 2 objects that were saved no problem. Using `find()` yielded no issues either. However, when I entered the following:

`db.food.find().sort({averageRating:-1}).select({_id: 1}).limit(2)`

I get the error:

`JS Error: TypeError: Object DBCursor has no method 'sort'`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
db.food.find({},{_id:1}).sort({"averageRating":-1}).limit(2);
```

It selects only 2 id fields ordered by average rating descending.The fields that are to be returned are specified by the second parameter in find(),which in this case is _id.

select is not a valid command in mongoDb as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah you are right but I can confirm that this is working in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It should be selector, not select. See if that fixes it.

Comment: are you sure that food is a collection?  Does it show up in the output of 'show collections' command?

Comment: hmm it doesnt... btw i'm using http://try.mongodb.org/ to test the commands...`db.food.find()` shows output

Comment: It says right there that it supports only a subset of the real shell's features.  Perhaps sort is not one of them.  Try installing mongo locally.  Your example will work as expected.  I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

As per shargors' comment, it looks like try.mongodb.org doesn't support sort().  I would recommend [downloading](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) and [installing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart) mongodb itself, and playing around with the real shell.